# How do I make notifications still flow when discussion is moved from comments to chat?

Tags: discussion, comments, chat, notifications, global-inbox

After the comments moved to chat, the discussion looks more "at home".

But global inbox notifications stop coming. So continuing the discussion a day later feels like posting to `/dev/null`.

For [one post](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/127369/5387) I have moved the comments to chat, then replied to the next appeared message in chat.

Not being not sure that my reply will actually go though, I suggested to explicitly look at the chat as another comment. And, although I got a reply suggesting that my chat message was seen, I have received a notification for the comment, but not for the "Sorry... It didn't work. Guess some other reason." chat post.

This lowers my trust in chat as comments substitute... The "move comments to chat" feels like "mark all those comments as a trifle not worthy of notifications"...

How do I keep updated for the chat associated with a Stack Exchange post ad infinitum?

Comment: Blame caching. And, btw, http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/93077/how-do-i-set-battery-charge-min-max-range-to-make-it-degrade-with-time-less/127369#comment158095_127369

Comment: @nicael, Yes, this comments suggests that the peer has received the notification. But _I_ have _not_ received. I see "Yes. Received  and  replied on chat please" comment in my global inbox, but not the chat message notification.

Comment: This is because you weren't pinged - the room, despite of having the name as being just for two people, is a regular chat room, where, to get a notification, you must get @pinged.

Comment: Shall there be some auto-suggestions how to behave in a chat room to make it like a comment? Users coming to chat after comments may suggest that the chat works the same as comments. Will this @ping work after few months of chat inactivity by the way?

Comment: After a few months it'll thouroughly frozen (and could be removed for inactivity), like a regular chat room (again), so as you can't post messages there any longer, unless you ask a mod to unfreeze it.

Comment: You can't. You should rephrase this as a feature-request I think :)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ, "You can't" -> I can't what? 1. Subscribe to chat so I receive notifications about all messages? 2. Ping users even after long period of inactivity (but before the chat is frozen)

Comment: You can't make the conversation flow without specifically replying to each user in chat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sup>Summary from comments by @nicael and @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ:</sup>

No, the chat root is not directly associated with the post and behaves like a usual chat room.

The user failed to use "@vi" ping contruction required to send notifications from chat. Unlike with comments, this doesn't happen automatically.

This is why he received a notification about your post, but not vice versa.