# Explain users about difference between chat notification and comment notification when comments are moved to chat

Tags: feature-request, comments, chat, comment-to-chat-migration

I suggest a hint about using explicit `@someuser` ping to be used in a char room that is based on migrated comments from StackExchange post. The hint should explain that automatic notification of post author that worked in comments does not longer work in chat, so writing `@targetuser` is a must to send a notification.

The failure scenario is this:

1. Answer is posted by user1;
2. User2 exchange many comments with user1 for this answer. User2 does not know about `@pinguser` feature at all;
3. Comments are moved to chat;
4. User2 keeps on posting comments (now in chat), without adding `@user1`, thinking that messages (like comments before) will get though to user1.

When the chat is still "hot" (i.e. the window with the chat is still opened by User1) this is more a big problem. But continuing the discussion on the next day may be problematic.

So on point "4." a message may be shown, suggesting the user to add `@user1`.

Maybe it can be generalized and chat should suggest adding some @'s anytime he tried to post to the room where he is alone.

Comment: link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268708/how-do-i-make-notifications-still-flow-when-discussion-is-moved-from-comments-to/268709#268709