# Is the OP notified of all chat messages after comments are moved to chat?

Tags: support, comments, chat, ping

The comments on a question are moved to chat. The discussion continues in chat. Will the OP be pinged for every single message in chat, just like OP would have been on normal comments on the question? Or is it just like normal chat where people are only pinged when you @ them?

What if there are only OP and one other person? Is OP always pinged then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on [this discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268708/307988), the following [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268711/307988) and personal experience—no, notifications do not carry over from chat. The created chat room has no direct association with the post it was migrated from so OP (or anyone else) will not be notified unless they were a part of the conversation and are @pinged.

As soon as the comments are migrated to chat, they behave just like (and are) a normal chat room. Anyone who joins the room will be pingable, but not before joining the room and not without the use of the @ping.